# Upper bound for $\frac{b^n}{n!}\int_0^\pi x^n(\pi -x)^n \sin x\, dx,\, n\in\mathbb{N}_0,\, b\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, pi

In this [article](https://mathscholar.org/2018/09/simple-proofs-the-irrationality-of-pi/) it is argued that
$$\frac{b^n}{n!}\int_0^\pi x^n(\pi -x)^n \sin x\, dx\le \frac{\pi b^n}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n},\, n\in\mathbb{N}_0,\, b\in\mathbb{N},$$
since $x(\pi -x)\le \frac{\pi ^2}{4}$.
But I don't understand why the author didn't use a better bound, namely $\frac{2b^n}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n}$, which can be seen by evaluating
$$\frac{b^n}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n}\int_0^\pi \sin x\, dx.$$
Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Why would the author require a better bound? They were just proving that the upper bound tends to something less than $1$.

Comment: So that "$\pi$ bound" was arbitrary?

Comment: No they were just using the standard bound $$\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x\le (b-a)\cdot\text{max}\{f(x):a\le x\le b\}$$for positive functions $f(x)$.